# Speed Up Visual Studio Publish Web Process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional to deploy my ASP.Net MVC website.

The problem is that when I use the one click publish feature, my web application comes to a screeching halt and it takes about 5 minutes for the website to respond normally again.

What are some things I can do to speed up this process to reduce or eliminate the amount of downtime for my users?

Comment: Are you using Web Deploy, File System, or FTP, etc.?

Comment: I am using web deploy.

Comment: Does the site just run slow immediately after deployment or do requests in fact timeout?  If the site is just laggy you may find that caching is the cause.  Take a look at what's going on with Fiddler or a similar tool, that should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I publish to a separate copy of the site on the live server and I have a script which I then run on the server to compare the live site with the copy and only update new/changed files/directories and delete removed ones.  This cuts down the downtime quite a bit, especially if there have only been minor changes.